# How can I link cells between two sheets so that value gets updated on the second sheet

Tags: excel

I have a workbook with several sheets. I have dates on the sheets that i update to same value daily.

eg. on sheet 1, the date is in cell A1, on sheet 2, the date is in cell C2, does not follow a particular order but i update them to same value daily.

Is there anyway i can link the cells, so any change made in one affects the rest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, why not enter the following formula in cell C2 on Sheet2?

```
=Sheet1!A1
```

Then you only have to change values on one sheet.

Answer (score 0):

For giving the linkages between two cells either in same sheet or any other sheet in the same excel file follow the following steps:-

1) Go to the column where you want to put the linkage.Press '=+' sign over there and then scroll to the column from where you want its linkage. and simply press the enter button.  you can also check in future from where the link has been given by pressing the 'ctrl+{' button in the cell where the link has been entered. it will take you automatically to the base value.